# "Scan" in French

Tags: choix-de-mot, informatique

I'm trying to translate the word "scanned copy" into French. At first, I used Google Translate, it gave me: "copie numérisée". Then I searched on http://dictionnaire.tv5.org/, the word "numériser" means "digitize", which seems not to be what I'm looking for.

Could anyone help me to translate this word correctly?

Comment: Can we have the complete sentence where you need to use it?

Comment: Good question!  But In your specific context, where it appears that you will be attaching a scanned copy of something to an e-mail (& making reference to it in the e-mail), perhaps you could avoid the notion of “scanned copy” altogether (does the recipient really care how you got the image into your computer?) by simply referring to it as “a copy” (as suggested by @Random) [& maybe noting its format]: “I’m attaching (or ‘Please find attached’) a copy of the [said] document [in .pdf format]" (or tif/jpg/bmp/gif/etc) = Ci-joint une copie du[dit] document [en format PDF /tif/jpg/bmp/gif/etc].

Comment: @Papa Poule: I really like your phrase: Ci-joint une copie du[dit] document [en format PDF /tif/jpg/bmp/gif/etc], very simple and concise!

Answer (score 7):

The first word I see is "**une copie numérique**". This can apply when you have an official paper document, and you scan it to have it on your computer.
"**Copie numérisée**" sounds strange to me, but is correct.

For the real translation of "to scan", we often say "**scanner**" in a familiar context. "**Numériser**" is a nicer translation, but rarely used when talking to someone you know. You often use "**numériser**" to an administration, or on a user manual etc.

You could also say "**une copie**", but it may add ambiguity on the nature of the document. If the context makes it clear, there is no problem.

Comment: Thanks! My case is formal as I have to send an email to an administrator. So based on your explanation, I should use "une copie numérique", am I correct?

Comment: You get it ! :)

Comment: You could always use "une copie" (dropping the scanned) which would probably be more appropriate.

Comment: @GAMPUB Indeed, it makes sense. But I think it may add ambiguity on the nature of the document. I added it to the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

L'[Office québécois de la langue française](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/) recommande *[numériser](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=507637)* mais propose aussi *scanner* pour le verbe. Pour l'[action](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8358469), quatre termes sont considérés comme privilégiés : *numérisation par balayage*, *numérisation*, *scannage* et *scannérisation*. Cette dernière fiche note :

> Bien qu'il y ait une distinction entre la numérisation par balayage (en anglais, *scanning*) et la numérisation (en anglais, *digitizing*), dans l'usage, on utilise le terme *numérisation* pour désigner la numérisation par balayage.

En pratique, en France, je n'ai jamais vu ou entendu *scannage* ou *scannérisation*. En général, on dit « un scan » (prononcé [skan]), mais on trouve aussi « numériser » pour le verbe et quelquefois « copie numérique » ou « copie numérisée » pour l'action ou l'objet (virtuel) produit.

Si tu veux parler français sans effaroucher les gens qui craignent les anglicismes, utilise « une copie numérique ». Si tu veux simplement être compris par des francophones, utilise « un scan ».

Comment: En France, je n'ai jamais entendu "scannérisation", et je serais en effet "choqué" de l'entendre :)

Comment: Un scan ayant un côté légèrement familier, dans les messages plus soutenus, on lit souvent les expressions suivantes « copie scannée », « pièce-jointe scannée ».

Answer (score 4):

"une numérisation" or "une copie numérisée" is correct. Yes, "numériser" means "digitize", because we convert analogic signal to digital signal. But very often, we just say "un scan". Also, if the scan is printed, we say "une photocopie".

Comment: Thanks! So you mean "un scan", "une copie numérisée", or "une numérisation" are all the same? If my case is formal, which one should I use?

Comment: @cl-r Opinion based comment (I would say the contrary)

Comment: @ SiXUlm As Random said, "une copie numérique" or "une copie numérisée" is the most formal.

Comment: à noter , que dans ce cas l'anglais est moins précis que le français, un "scan" n'est nécessairement suivi d'une numérisation . *I scanned this poem* ne veut pas forcément dire que je l'ai fait avec un appareil, ce peut-être fait du regard. "Scan" veut aussi dire scruter/analyser/regarder en passant. Aucun doute avec "j'ai numérisé ce document".

Answer (score 2):

Reading comments, the context is :

> My case is formal as I have to send an email to an administrator.

And even if other answers recommend *"**scan**"* which is the word the most commonly used, if you need to be more formal, you can write :

> Ci-joint la **numérisation** du document [...]