# Le document, la copie, la version [sur] « papier » ?

Tags: informatique, terminologie

Dans un autre contexte, on se questionne sur la [*numérisation*](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/13942). La question porte ici sur l'antonyme du [*document numérique*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_num%C3%A9rique) et son usage. L'article *Wikipédia* mentionne :

> La notion de document numérique s'oppose à celle de document sur
> papier. Selon le contexte, il existe plusieurs adjectifs antonymes de
> "numérique" : document imprimé, document manuscrit, document matériel
> ou matérialisé. L'emploi du substantif "papier" comme adjectif est
> réprouvé par les autorités linguistiques francophones (Académie
> française, Office québecois de la langue française, notamment). "Dire
> ou écrire "*un document papier*", "*un dossier papier*" relève d'une
> connaissance défaillante de la langue française et d'une façon de
> s'exprimer tout à fait infantile"<sup>1</sup>.[la note renvoie à la
> [page d'accueil](http://www.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ressources/bdl.html) de la *BDL* !] En cas de doute sur l'antonyme précis
> de l'adjectif "numérique", il convient de former correctement le
> complément de nom : un *document numérique* s'oppose à un *document
> sur papier*.
>
> [ *Wikipédia* « document numérique » ]

En fait, la *BDL* traite du cas où le nom [*papier*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=papier&T3.x=0&T3.y=0) « *est parfois juxtaposé avec un autre nom, qu'il caractérise; il s’oppose alors à l’adjectif électronique. Dans cet emploi, papier complète le nom comme le ferait un complément introduit par une préposition et est invariable.* » On propose même les exemples suivants :

> *Ce document est introuvable : aucune trace de la clé de stockage sur
> laquelle il a été enregistré, ni des deux **copies papier** qu’on en avait
> faites!*
>
> *Lors de la perquisition, de l’argent, des **documents papier** et des
> fichiers informatiques ont été saisis.*
>
> [ *BDL de l'OQLF* « papier » ]

Quant à l'*Académie française*, au dictionnaire on ne fait mention ni de l'emploi ni de la contre-indication ([papier](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/papier)([TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/papier)), [copie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/copie)([TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/copie)); aucune entrée contenant les deux termes sur *Franceterme*) et je ne trouve pas d'information spécifique sur le site web de l'*Académie* dans leurs [sections prescriptives](http://academie-francaise.fr/dire-ne-pas-dire) à défaut de savoir chercher au *Journal Officiel* de la République française.

Sur [*Termium*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=frt&srchtxt=COPIE%20PAPIER), on recense plusieurs emplois de *copie papier* pour traduire le terme anglais « *hard copy* », essentiellement la *copie d'écran*, dont une traduction standardisée de *ISO/IEC 2382-1:1993* etc. mais l'emploi varie selon le domaine. Le *GDT* parle d'une [*copie papier*](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=502847) comme de la « *[r]eproduction de données en mémoire sur un support papier, parfois pour répondre à des impératifs de contrôle.* ». On a une autre entrée pour [*version papier*](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8362459); on y mentionne que  « *[l]a version papier est un exemplaire d'un ouvrage ou d'un document, alors que la copie papier est une reproduction sur un support papier.* ». On traite aussi de la différence entre la copie et l'exemplaire à la [*BDL*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2454) à l'extérieur du cadre technologique : « *En résumé, on appelle copie la reproduction fidèle d’un original et on appelle exemplaire chacun des objets reproduits en série. Ces deux mots ne sont donc pas interchangeables : le mot copie s’emploie pour désigner le double d’un contrat, d’une lettre, d’un document, d’un acte notarié, etc., et le mot exemplaire s’emploie pour tout ce qui est publié[...]* ». Enfin, on peut tenter d'observer la réalité sur le terrain ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=document+papier%2Cdocument+sur+papier%2Ccopie+papier%2Ccopie+sur+papier%2Cversion+papier%2Cversion+sur+papier&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdocument%20papier%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdocument%20sur%20papier%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccopie%20papier%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccopie%20sur%20papier%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cversion%20papier%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cversion%20sur%20papier%3B%2Cc0)).

---

1. L'emploi du substantif « papier » comme adjectif dans « *document papier* » pour désigner l'antonyme du *document électronique* est-il « réprouvé » ?
2. La *copie papier* et la *copie sur papier* sont-ils des synonymes aujourd'hui ?
3. Si par exemple un document est rédigé à l'aide d'un logiciel de traitement de texte, imprimé, signé, puis numérisé et archivé - produit-on le cas échéant une *copie* ou une *version* papier de ce document à l'impression ?

Comment: I’m probably misinterpreting “Termium” and/or your discussion of it (and regardless, it doesn’t affect your question or answers/potential answers to it), but to whatever extent that “copie d'écran” could mean “screen shot/screen capture” in English (and that’s how I would, perhaps incorrectly, translate it), could “hard copy” in English ever (in any domain) really essentially mean “copie d'écran” in French? I’d call “screen shot/capture” a near opposite of “hard copy,” or at least somewhere on the digital side of the dividing line between a “digital copy” and a “hard copy.”

Comment: @PapaPoule Thank you, I hear you. It's about the "printout"; termium is complicated; indeed a screen capture and a hard copy are mostly opposite; yet the latter can be a render on paper of the former, une sortie sur papier de ce qui est affiché à l'écran if you want. It is offtopic and not my field, but I get the feeling some terms were coined when you had terminals feeding to paper directly and such. Is the data formatted prior to output, or do you print with remnants of the interface; it seems software wraps printing more so than before. Words may pack more than what they were designed for.

Comment: Ce n'est qu'un point de détail, mais je dirais que le substantif (nature ou classe) *papier* est apposé, pas qu'il est employé comme adjectif (nature ou classe également).

Answer (score 1):

1. Tu as pu trouver  sur le site de l'OQLF des exemples concerts ainsi qu'une règle "de non-accord" applicable à ce cas là, donc logiquement, cet emploi n'est pas réprouvé. De plus, les langues évoluant, cet expression s'est répandue et ne sera donc pas reprochée.
2. Comme tu l'as toi-même écrit : « Copie papier » =  « Reproduction sur support papier ». Et donc, c'est identique à « Copie sur papier ».
3. À la première impression, tu auras des « versions papier ». Aux impressions suivantes, des « copies papier », car tu reproduiras un document qui aura préalablement été stocké en mémoire.

Comment: Pour la 3 : À la première impression, tu auras des « versions papier ». Quand elles sont signées et numérisées et à nouveau éditées ces impressions sont des « copies papier »

Comment: Merci! 1. Bien ce pourrait être un régionalisme terminologique non ? J'aimerais bien savoir si l'Académie a un point de vue sur le sujet tel que le suggère Wikipédia, car c'est ainsi qu'on peut affirmer avec certitude que l'emploi n'est pas réprouvé en France. 3. Peut-on préciser, si je redémarre l'ordinateur entre les deux impressions, ai-je deux « versions papier » ?